# AngularJS hide div using ng-show on ng-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

My goal is to get rid of the error messages with a button click. So I thought I'd just clear the field on button click and hence, get ride of the error. It worked in my very first test.

```
<div class="errorPopup" 
data-ng-click="runner.Name = null" 
data-ng-show="mainForm.name.$error.pattern">
      <div class="triangle-down pull-left"></div>
      <span>Only letters allowed.</span>
</div>
<input ng-model="runner.Name" data-ng-patter="/(a-z)\" required />
```

But now I have to click once.. clearing the field. then click twice before the error div is deleted.

I'd like to get rid of the field and the div in one click

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough information to help you.  It is not obvious to me what mainForm.name is; nor when it would change.  Can you put together a plunker to show the problem?  If I had to guess; you need to force a $digest.$apply() on the first click.

Comment: Don't try your code sample, but wouldn't it be easier using ng-pattern and not ng-patter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code (assumign that there **is** a wrapping form with the name `mainForm`):

- `data-ng-patter` should be `data-ng-pattern`
- The regular expressions is not correct. If you want to only allow lowercase latin letters:
  `/^[a-z]*$/`
- In order to check for an error in the input field (and reference it via `mainForm.name.$error`) the field **must** have a name. Since you are referring to it as `mainForm.name` it needs a name of `name` (which is not intuitive). Choose something representative (e.g. `runnerName`) and use it like this:

```
<input type="text" name="runnerName" ... />

<div ... ng-show="mainForm.runnerName.$error">
```

If you fix those issues, every seems to work fine !

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/93RD5/)**.